# Cannot access the BIOS while CSM is disabled

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, secure-boot

I've disabled CSM in the BIOS of the DS3H B450 motherboard, because it is required for secure boot (which in turn is required to update to Windows 11) but doing so has locked me out of the rest of the process of enabling secure boot. (It requires a restart after disabling CSM, and then you can enable secure boot.) Attempting to get into the BIOS GUI, or even the logo from the manufacturer, displays as `Input not supported`. I can fix this by clearing the CMOS, but it doesn't fix the issue of not having secure boot.

I'm using the RX 570 and Ryzen 3 1200. I'm not sure if this is a driver issue or if I'm permanently not able to use secure boot.

Comment: You are aware that your processor is technically not compatible with the system requirements for Windows 11?  As for the problem you describe how are you connected to your monitor?

Comment: My monitor is connected by HDMI, and I know that my processor isn't technically compatible, but it should still work.

Comment: If you upgrade to a Windows 11 Insider Preview you will ultimately be downgraded to Windows 10 once the Windows RTM is released